# Is it possible to have subnets for hosts connected to a switch?

Tags: networking, network-design

**re-EDIT** I can not provide my attempts and what wen't wrong, because I am only doing the design and not actually implementing right now. Although the goal of this structure is a school network. I reduced the numbers a lot, but basically: the router would be sending the traffic out of the school network. The one switch connected to it would be sitting in an IT room and the other 5 switches will be inside 5 class rooms. One in each. In the class room there are 20 computers for the students and each of these computers is connected to the switch. What I would like to know is, if each class room can be under one subnet, even though they are connected to a switch and not a router. I hope this helps.

I am making a network design and I am struggling with what is probably a very simple logic. Here goes: 
When I have 1 router. Connect to it 1 switch. Connect 5 switches to it. And then connect 20 Computers to each of the 5 switches, is it possible to have 5 subnets for each of the switches and the hosts? Or because they are all switches there can only be one subnet on the router?

I hope it makes any sense, thank you in advance for your replies.

Comment: Subnets require a single broadcast domain, and you can have multiple subnets per broadcast domain, but likely shouldn't. Whatever you're trying to do, you're almost certainly *Doing It Wrong™*.

Comment: **On Hold** doesn't mean that it's dead and buried.  Sometimes it just needs a bit of work.  The on hold text says *Try including attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results.*  What are you trying to achieve with this design?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. You simply need to give the router an interface on each of the subnets you create.

Comment: but In that design I only have one interface on the router, the interface is connected to the 1 switch. So basically I can't do it with this design?

Comment: The number of virtual interfaces isn't necessarily related to the number of physical interfaces. You can create multiple virtual interfaces on different networks on the same physical interface using your router's OS.

Comment: virtual interface = VLAN though, right? I wanted to have pre set 5 subnets for each of the switches and the hosts and then group them in the VLAN again just for easier re-routing or whatnot

Answer (score 0):

You want to create [VLANs](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/switches/lan/catalyst6500/ios/12.2SX/configuration/guide/vlans.html). A virtual lan will help you segregate your traffic by, in this case, physical switch.

Comment: Ok so I will put all the 20hosts and 5 switches into one subnet. And then with VLAN i will divide them into groups to my liking?

Comment: I'd do 1 subnet per VLAN, e.g. 10.10.x.0/24 where x=11-15.  You can also use x as your VLAN ID.

Comment: That's what I wanted to do, but that is why I asked the main question. Can I have each of the 20 hosts & switch as one subnet even though they are connected to a switch and not a router?

Comment: That is the default configuration.  You don't need to do anything, just create one subnet and have all the machines use the default VLAN.

Comment: Is that so, any nice documentation that sums this up? Probably should read that.. Thank you.